# jquery-How to limit characters when p class in jquery process?

Tags: jquery

this my code which I want to limit the characters in paragraph based on class,but it not working because p class I have created in jquery process.

```
$('.go-back').click(function(){
     if($('.item').hasClass('active')){
        var current ='';
        current += '<p class="descSub">'+$('.active').find('.title').html()+'</p>';

        // code to limit characters of p class above 
        var titleLength = $('.descSub');
        titleLength.text(titleLength.text().substring(0,20));
        $('.content').html(current);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding this correctly, just change the order in which dictate the character limit. In your example you are doing it after you have it appended, all you need to do is do it before.

```
 $('.go-back').click(function(){
 if($('.item').hasClass('active')){

    var current ='';
    //grab title from active .title first
    var titleLength = $('.active').find('.title').html();
    //then crop to 20 chars max
    titleLength = titleLength.substring(0,20);
    //then add to current
    current += '<p class="descSub">'+ titleLength +'</p>';
    //then put to .contents html
    $('.content').html(current);
 }

});
```

Fiddle here so you can see it in action : https://jsfiddle.net/0rfebv0e/8/

Comment: Thanks, I think still not luck,not get anycontent,and when I put alert(current) ,it's also not show alert popup.

Comment: @den sorry, i didnt check that substring function - it was formatted incorrectly. I fixed it for you, check code now. Added fiddle for you too!